# Sending Email to my gmail account

Tags: php

I am able to send emails from my Mercury mail server to my Gmail account, but when I try to it using the `mail()` function in PHP, it doesn't work! Why?

```
<?php
if(mail('XYZ@gmail.com','NICE','OK'))
{
echo "success";
}
?>
```

It shows "Success" in my browser but there's no mail in my mailbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email using GMail SMTP server from PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

Comment: Are you executing your script on your desktop computer? On a server? Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: I guess a mail without a specified sender will ALWAYS be considered spam.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot debug issues like this without having access to the logfile of the mail server you are using to send your email.

However, if it's a machine connected via dialup (i.e. one that is not in a datacenter) you are very unlikely to be able to send *any* emails to the big email providers as they are going to block your emails - usually only spam comes from MTAs running on dialup hosts.

Comment: I think the assumption of dialup only applies to third world countries. Majority of the SP now allow mail protocol and is not blocked. I can tell you verizon does not block smtp. But good point to bring up, incase this person is from third world country

Comment: Well I didn't mean *actual* dialup but pretty much any home connections. Try connecting e.g. to a gmail or hotmail MTA using netcat/telnet and you can be pretty sure it rejects you before you even finished throwing a complete email at it.

Answer (score 0):

have you check your spam filters? or is your mail server setup on php.ini? did u setup smtp authentication? documented by this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.setup.php

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It turned out that my smart-relay was missing in the mail configuration.